# Excel 2010 - Pivot using external csv file - how to make dates work?

Tags: date, csv, datasource, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a set of pivot tables that use external csv files as their data sources. The csv files originally contained dates in the format dd/mm/yy (e.g. 31/01/13). The pivot tables did not recognise these as dates. I converted the dates in the csv files to dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. 31/01/2013) but these were still not recognised as dates by the pivot tables.

I tried setting up a calculated field =DATEVALUE(date_from_csv) but when used in the pivot table (I'm using the Max option to select the most recent date) I get #VALUE! errors.

I have tried converting the csv file to xlsx and also importing the data into the workbook that contains the pivot table - but I can't change from the external connection to use the internal data. I don't want to rebuild the pivots as there are a lot of variables and formatting that would take ages to redo.

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried setting the date to 01/31/2013, instead? This is most likely caused by regional settings. Personally, I stick with ISO (eg 2013-01-31).

Comment: The problem was caused by the date column being blank for some rows and I found that if I moved a row to the top (after the header line) that had all the fields filled in, then Excel got the formats correct and the pivot tables now work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the date column being blank for some rows and I found that if I moved a row to the top (after the header line) that had all the fields filled in, then Excel got the formats correct and the pivot tables now work!